# Error when inserting into a simple two column table with SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running the following:

```
insert into [authentication].[dbo].[AspNetUserRoles] ("RoleId","UserId") 
values ("0918fb0f-79c0-4298-b184-9a754dc5c30e", "527ddbd5-14d3-4fb9-a7ae-374e66f635d4")
```

Here's my table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles] (
    [RoleId] NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    [UserId] NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL
);
```

However it's giving me an error saying:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid column name '0918fb0f-79c0-4298-b184-9a754dc5c30e'.
```

Is there something wrong with the way I have coded the insert ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the values in `''` not `""`:

```
insert into [authentication].[dbo].[AspNetUserRoles] ("RoleId","UserId") 
values ('0918fb0f-79c0-4298-b184-9a754dc5c30e',
        '527ddbd5-14d3-4fb9-a7ae-374e66f635d4');
```

The problem is that the values with `""` around them are treated as identifiers not literals. Like in `"RoleId","UserId"`.